How to add information about topic to metrics of Spring Kafka Template?
I have metric "spring_kafka_template_seconds_count" but there are no topic information. I use 2.8.11 spring-kafka version. In doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/micrometer.html they say that
Starting with versions 2.9.8, 3.0.6, you can provide a KafkaTemplate.setMicrometerTagsProvider(Function<ProducerRecord<?, ?>, Map<String, String>>) property; 
the function receives the ProducerRecord<?, ?> and returns tags which can be based on that record, 
and merged with any static tags in micrometerTags. 

but I dont know how to increase version of Kafka 2.8.11 -> 2.9.8 safely (my Spring boot version is 2.7.18).
Is there are a way to add additional information to metrics, or add my custom metrics to Kafka template?
Or is there are a guide how to increase spring-kafka version safely (or maybe a list of versions compatibility)?
I tried create bean implementing ProducerListener<Object, Object> and override onSuccess and onError methods, but if I will add ProducerListener bean to context, the LoggingProducerListener wont be created by autoconfiguration:
public class KafkaAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ProducerListener.class)
    public LoggingProducerListener<Object, Object> kafkaProducerListener() {
        return new LoggingProducerListener<>();
    }


You asked for Actuator metrics. Why do you need the logging listner?


dont know how to increase version ... safely

The Spring documentation covers this in enough detail regarding breaking and deprecated changes. This is a perfect time to learn how to keep your code up-to-date. Even to Spring Boot 3+, if you have to.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/upgrading.html

guide how to increase spring-kafka version safely

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/appendix/change-history.html
Just change the version in your pom/gradle file(s) and recompile. Check if there are errors, run the unit-tests, if you have any, etc.


Metrics

KafkaProducer & KafkaConsumer have their own JMX Metrics exposed by Micrometer. It's not clear if you really need extras from Spring-Kafka.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#kafka-monitoring-metrics-producer
